# Loading Screen on Separate Thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

So, I've been scouring Stack for a solution and there are tons of issues over Threading, but I haven't found one that really fits my exact scenario.  I have a WPF Window `LoadingWindow` and a Boolean value in my main Window `BusyBool`.  There are several instances throughout the main application where I know it is going to take a minute to load data, so at the start I set `BusyBool` to True, and when the process completes I set `BusyBool` to false.  The goal was that when `BusyBool` is True, the loading window displays on a separate thread, when it is set to false it closes (rinse and repeat).

What I thought should work is creating a thread, starting it, and then calling the Window.Show() and Window.Close() from the main UI thread without having to destroy and recreate the thread over and over.  I could really use help getting the implementation to work.  Here is my code as it is now:

```
   public MainWindow()
    {
        Uri iconuri = new Uri("Assets/logo.jpg", UriKind.Relative);

        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    }

    public Boolean BusyBool
    {
        get { return _busybool; }
        set
        {
            if (_busybool != value)
            {
                _busybool = value;

                if(value == true)
                {
                    FireThread();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void FireThread()
    {
        MainWindow main = App.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow;
        LoadingScreen load = new LoadingScreen(main);

        newWindowThread = new Thread(() => load.Show());
        newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        newWindowThread.IsBackground = true;
        newWindowThread.Start();
    }
}
```

I had reached a point where I have code in the Loading window to check the value periodically of BusyBool by passing an instance of the main window to it. Probably not the best implementation.

Comment: The way you do this is you display a busy window in the regular UI thread, and you do the work in a Task. When the work is done, the Task calls some callback that invokes into the UI thread to close the busy window. The Task isn't part of the busy window; it doesn't need to be. Just put the task stuff in a lambda that has a reference to `load` and closes it (via invoke of course) in a `finally` block at the end. Done.

Comment: Would this cause ALL the work being done currently in the UI thread to be moved to tasks?  I only ask because that could be a pretty substantial rewrite.

Comment: The only thing that can cause a line of your code to be in a Task is you putting it there. Or somebody else who has commit access to your source repository.

Comment: Ed, this just clicked.  Thanks for the help!